# Select Syllable to do action on it (change color, underline, etc...) // JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

hope everyone is fine.

I'm currently working for a project. I need to be able to select syllable in a word to change the style of this syllable (in every word). I actually find code for counting syllable , but nothing yet for changing style.

I'm new in the dev game, and i don't realy know where to start..

If anyone can help, i'll be gratefull (not asking for working code,just need track for me to be able to work it myself).

Thanks a lot,

Have a nice day.

Comment: Hello, could you provide some details abour your environment ? Is it text in DOM elements ? Or in a canvas context ? Provide a minimum reproducile code base of your problem could be useful too.

Comment: Yes sorry, i'm just working on a simple site with HTML , CSS and JS only. It's a volunteer project to help writing book for dyslexique people. I have a input with the text people write, and when they validate the input, i need to transform this text in a div with the style add (for them to be able to just copy and past the text on word for exemple).

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Helping with issues like that is hard without any provided code and things you've tried.

Comment: The styling of the text in an html document is not comapatible with the format of a word document (as far as I know..). those two contexts are completely differents and you will just be able to copy the text itself. Anyway for the HTML part could you provide some code to show what you've done so far ?

Comment: Thanks for your awser , i'll try to code something and i'll post it here when i'll be more advance in my project. Thanks a lot.